# Connect to rasberry pi via a server

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi

I have a raspberry pi that is behind a NAT and want to somehow ssh to it through, for example, an AWS t3.micro instance, when I'm not in the local network. What are some easy and reliable ways to connect to the device?

I was thinking of a VPN tunnel from the raspberry pi to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reverse ssh tunneling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46235/how-does-reverse-ssh-tunneling-work). If you have access to a public server `S`, what you can do is to init a reverse ssh connection from the raspberry pi to `S`, on a custom port, and then from any other computer, ssh on `S` and then ssh on the `localhost`, with the raspberry pi user, on your custom port.

So,

```
PI> ssh -l <S_user> <S> -R <port>:localhost:22 -o ServerAliveInterval=10
PC> ssh -l <S_user> <S>
PC> ssh -l <pi_user> localhost -p <port>
```

Comment: Cool response, Alex! Can't wait to set it up in practice!